# Vulnerability in DES3 when key can be chosen

Tags: block-cipher, des, attack, chosen-plaintext-attack

In the question there are two functions encrypt basically does  IV ⨁ DES3(P⨁IV) and encrypt_flag just encrypts the flag after being padded into a multiple of 8. IV is a random 8 byte number which is always constant.

I have been looking at this question for a long time and I can't work it out. The question is to find the value of the flag by submitting encrypt(key, plaintext) and encrypt_flag() requests. I have thought that if plaintext='0000000000000000' then ciphertext=cipher.encrypt(IV)^IV but I have researched and haven't managed to find a vulnerability there. I also thought of saying key='000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' but that doesn't work since it isn't DES3 anymore as it degenerates to DES. The flag starts with crypto{ and we don't know it's length and it also finishes with }. The requests are made through an oracle, you send the requests as hex numbers. for encrypt_flag you just send the key as hex and it will return the flag encrypted as described above. With encrypt request you send a key and plaintext as hex number and it encrypts them as described above and then returns the ciphertext. So:

encrypt(plaintext, key)->IV ⨁ DES3(P⨁IV) where ⨁ denotes bitwise xor

and

encrypt_flag(key)->encrypt(padded(flag), key)

My intuition tells me that the vulnerability is in the fact we can select the key, but I can't think how that can make it vulnerable

Comment: "python gives error" means you should probably use `key = binascii.unhexlify('000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')`

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude when I said it gives error, I didn't mean about the fact it's in hex, I meant it gives error in the DES3. It gives the following error: {"error":"Triple DES key degenerates to single DES"}

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I've edited it, so that it is clearer

Comment: Python code does not belong here, use pseudocodes or mathematical notations instead. But for your question, are you first padding your FLAG to 8 bytes (64 bits), then making hex string (16 bytes or two blocks of 3DES) and then encrypting it? If your IV is first generated and constant all over (thus known), then it is not secure under chosen plain text attacks. Again, I don't know what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @ManishAdhikari IV is first generated and constant all over, but it is not known to use

Comment: @ManishAdhikari there is padding to the flag, the padding is 8 bytes and it is padded first

Comment: Still I don't get your encrypt_flag, describe clearly what it is. And get rid of codes, mods might remove your question otherwise. Explain clearly what you are trying to do. And, does python allow directly encrypting string without doing bytes()?

Comment: @ManishAdhikari the plaintext which is getting encrypted is already in bytes plaintext = bytes.fromhex(plaintext)

Comment: @ManishAdhikari basically the encrypt_flag returns the flag encrypted with the scheme described in encrypt(key, plaintext) with a key of your choosing (which you will give it as hex), after it gets padded so that its length is a multiple of 8. the encrypt(key, flag) function receives as input a key and a flag of your choosing in hex and then it encrypts it. It's encrypting goes as follows:
There is a random IV which is always the same and it takes the xor of plaintext with the iv. It then encrypts this with DES3 which has as a key, the key which you have already defined and then it xors the re

Comment: So it is single block encryption IV ⨁ DES3(P⨁IV), right?

Comment: @ManishAdhikari exactly you described it perfectly

Comment: @ManishAdhikari Should I remove the code from the question, or just edit it and put an explanation underneath so that it is more clear?

Comment: Use pseudocodes, you do not post codes here. Not everyone might be familiar with the said language

Comment: @ManishAdhikari ok I'll try, although I've never written a pseudocode before

Comment: @ManishAdhikari is this better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124790/discussion-between-manish-adhikari-and-michael-blane).